# How to become a Stand-by Block Producer

Tags: block-producer

Is there a document / wiki etc. out there that provides details on how to become a stand-by block producer for EOS?

Comment: Your aim should be to become a block producer.

Answer (score 1):

Stand-by block producers are the ones that are between 21 and +-50 in rank of votes. Once you have moved into that area in the rank table you are a stand-by block producer.

See also https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/8s2kpc/howto_become_a_block_producer/